# How to keep white spaces in the beginning of string from json response rendered by Kendo DataSource?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

DataSource gets json response data:

```
        categoriesDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "{{ path('get_json_categories') }}",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
        });
```

with white spaces:

```
{"categoryId":33,"parentId":32,"name":"    [ ] p1"}
```

but rendering it without white spaces. How to change this behaviour?

---

edit: I need whitespaces in select options input. Below is my template script

```
 <script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <form method="post" action="{{ path('updatedoc') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="documentFile">Plik</label>
            </div>
            <div data-container-for="documentFile" class="k-edit-field">
                <input name="files" id="files" type="file" aria-label="files"/>
            </div>
            <input name="documentId" id="documentId" type="text" data-bind="value:documentId" style="display: none;"/>

            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="documentDateAdd">Data Dodania</label>
            </div>
            <div class="k-edit-field">
                <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox k-state-disabled" name="documentDateAdd"
                       data-bind="value:documentDateAdd" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="documentDesc">Opis</label>
            </div>
            <div data-container-for="documentDesc" class="k-edit-field">
                <textarea name="documentDesc" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:documentDesc"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="user">Twórca</label>
            </div>
            <div data-container-for="user" class="k-edit-field">
                <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox k-state-disabled" name="user" data-bind="value:user"
                       disabled>
            </div>

            <!-- dropdownlist-->
            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="FacultyRankId">Kategoria</label>
            </div>
            <!-- dropdownlist editor for field: "FacultyRankId" -->
            <div class="k-edit-field" id="categoriesDiv">
                <input id="categoriesInput" name="categoryId"
                        {# tu wskazuję z którą wartością z data-source wiązać ten input tj z czym synchronizować, czyli
                         zmiany w inpucie na które pole ma wpływać z dataSource#}
                       data-bind="value:categoryId"
                       data-value-field="categoryId"
                        {#to co jest wyświetlane w dropdown#}
                       data-text-field="name"
                       data-source="categoriesDS"
                       data-role="dropdownlist"
                       data-value-primitive="true"
                />
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.k-edit-buttons:eq(1)').hide();
                $("span.k-dropdown-wrap > span.k-input").each(function() {
                    console.log($(this).text());
                    var text = $(this).text().replace('PODKATEGORIA666, ', '.   .');
                    $(this).text(text);
                });


            <\/script>
                <div class="k-edit-buttons k-state-default">
                    <button type="submit" class="k-button k-primary"> Aktualizuj </button>
                </div>
            </form>
    </script>
```

and style selector that didn't work:

```
<style>
    input#categoriesInput { white-space: pre; }
</style>
```

[image]
(It looks like your post is mostly bar code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code;  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `white-space` style to `pre` and depending on the widget that you want to use it you will have to use different selectors.

Following an example for showing it in a drop down list:

```
<style>
  span[aria-owns="color_listbox"] { white-space: pre; }
  #color-list .k-item { white-space: pre; }
</style>
```

Following a snippet

```js
 $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
      { text: "     [ ] Black", value: "1" },
      { text: "       [ ] Orange", value: "2" },
      { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
    ]
  });
```

```css
span[aria-owns="color_listbox"] {
  white-space: pre;
}

#color-list .k-item {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="color" value="1" style="width: 100%;" />
```

Comment: I need both those selectors style? i did it once by copying selector from chrome browser pointed to input that i want whitespacees off and it didnt work `#categoriesDiv > span > span > span.k-input { white-space: pre; }`. Please take a look to my main post to tell if my selector is good. i updated code .

Comment: You mention `categoriesDiv` in you reply but I cannot see it in your code. What is `categoriesDiv`? Which KendoUI widget are you defining? Datasource is not relevant here. What matters is the widget

Comment: My bad, I copied wrong part of code. I'm using DropDown Widget inside kendoGrid (dropdown edit row). Please check my template script in main post.

Comment: ok, it works. Problem was, that script rendering output is way different than chrome "source of the page" and dropdown widget contain <li> markdown, not <select>. So with this selector `ul#categoriesInput_listbox > li { white-space: pre; }` it works